# Get the values which is not present in table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, exists

I have table `IteamMaster` and query as below,

```
 Select ItemID from ItemMaster 
 Where ItemID IN(1,2,...,100)
```

this query returns me the all the values from the table which are available now what i want is 
the query should return the itemID which are not present in the table that is suppose My table has data as

```
  ItemId        ItemName
   1               x
   3               y
   4               z
   10              a
```

then it must return me the all the item id's except 1,3,4,10 from set of `IN()` conditions value ? How to get that values any help would be great ? 
And my values are dynamically generating and pass to the query query is also dynamically genrated

Comment: you mean all values from (1,2,3....100) except 1,3,4,10 ?

Comment: @VijaykumarHadalgi Yup

Comment: I think he's put commas to show any number of itemIds not necessarily his actual query

Comment: then jus try `select * from table where itemid NOT IN('1','3','4','10')`

Comment: @VijaykumarHadalgi no this will return only the rows which are not in array but in table i want the values from array which are not present in table not any other values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't magic values up out of no-where.  Whatever you select FROM must contain the value you want.  Using the system table `master..spt_value` you can generate a long list of values, and check for numbers that are in there, but not in your table...

```
;With Numbers as (
    select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY number) as n
    from master..spt_values
)

SELECT
  *
FROM
  Numbers
LEFT JOIN
  yourTable
    ON  Numbers.n = yourTable.ItemId
WHERE
      Numbers.n IN (1,2,...,100)
  AND yourTable.ItemID IS NULL
```

Or...

```
;With Numbers as (
    select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY number) as n
    from master..spt_values
)

SELECT
  *
FROM
  Numbers
WHERE
      Numbers.n IN (1,2,...,100)
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM yourTable WHERE ItemID = Numbers.n)
```

There are hundreds of ways of creating that initial list of numbers.  But create it you must.  Until you have the list of numbers than *can* exist, you can't select the numbers that *don't* currently exist.

Comment: Follow this logic and always try to use a not exist instead of a not in or a in. The not exists or exists will stop as soon as the condition is accepted or rejected, the not in follow the list

Comment: @MatBailie it works fine for the item id 1 to 2047 but again next of that it fails because `master..spt_values` generates that much values there is any way it can generate the given amount of numbres

Comment: @Curiosity - `There are hundreds of ways of creating that initial list of numbers.`  I suggest googling or searching StackOverflow.  A common method is to write a recursive CTE to create as many numbers as you need, but that calculation needs to happen every time you run this query.  Alternatively, perhaps, keeping them in a table of your own as a reference table *(create them all once, no need to calculate them every time you run this type of query)*.  Which of the many solutions to creating the list of numbers is best depends on your specific circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
Select ItemID from ItemMaster Where ItemID NOT IN(1,2,...,100)
```

Comment: It all depends what he puts in the NOT IN().  I've tested it on my database and it works

Comment: @AdRock : If the query has `IN(2)` but the table doesn't contain `id=2`, selecting from that table can not *ever* return the value `2`.  It's not in the table you're selecting from...

Comment: @MatBailie is correct i want the values form the `IN()` it doesn't matter if that id's present in table or not

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass a list of values and obtain only values not in your table you can pass them as values and then exclude values already in your table. As follows:

```
Select * from (values 1,2,...,100) except Select ItemID from ItemMaster
```

Update: this is db2 tested version, for sql server I needed to change a bit:

```
Select * from (values (1),(2),...,(100)) as temp(int) except Select ItemID from ItemMaster
```